# Terraform conditionally exclude a resource block

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

The below is specific to terraform .11 and works with .12

Below is the code I am using. It is a data block to get Image details from Azure shared Image Gallery.

I have a variable input parameter for **image_version**

I can give **image_version** as a particular version ( like * 1.0.1 or 1.0.2 * ) or can give input as * latest *

If you see the output block in below code , if the image_version is given as latest the 1st data section will be executed and latest image will be given as output
And if I give input NOT as latest - the 2nd data section will be executed and give that particular image ID will be given as output

So this output , I am using for virtual machine creation

```
### 1. latest section ####
data "azurerm_shared_image" "centos7" {
name                = "centos"
gallery_name        = "centos_galleries"
resource_group_name = "centos-galleries-rg"
}

### 2. image version number section ####
data "azurerm_shared_image_version" "centos7" {
name                = "1.0.1" ## [ This block fails when provided a dummy number ]
image_name          = "centos"
gallery_name        = "centos_galleries"
resource_group_name = "centos-galleries-rg"
}

output "id" {
value = "${var.image_version == "latest" ? data.azurerm_shared_image.centos7.id : data.azurerm_shared_image_version.centos7.id}"
}
```

Now the issue is, in 2nd data section I am giving name = 1.0.1 - which should be an existing version in Shared Image gallery.
If I gives a non existing version number in my code ( say name = 10.10.10 ) and gives my input image_version = latest , ideally only the 1st data section should be evaluated and should be working fine - but with terraform 11 - the 2nd data section also gets evaluated and it is failing with the name = 10.10.10 version is not existing. Here I gave input image_version = latest - still it is failing

So is there a way I can conditionally exclude a complete data section or is there a better way I can re-write this code?

Comment: can you offload this decision to a script where you can control the flow?

Comment: Have you tried `count` and splat when referring to the id?

Comment: Hi @JakubKania Yes tried with count,  but failing with below

Error refreshing state: 1 error occurred:
        * output.id: At column 3, line 1: true and false expression types must match; have type string and type list in:

Comment: @NiceThomas well, with count the 2nd data section shouldn't be evaluated so what was the problem when you tried it?

Comment: Yes , right  

when I give count = 0 for 2nd section, it complaints to give <star>.id for output section
so need to change the output as below

output "id" {
value = "${var.image_version == "latest" ? data.azurerm_shared_image.centos7.id : data.azurerm_shared_image_version.centos7.<star>.id}"
}

and when I gave <star> . id it gives error as below

output.id: At column 3, line 1: true and false expression types must match; have type string and type list in:

Comment: Thanks it works fine with count , the one which gives was warning and we can safely ignore that.